# NPgsql connection pool and performance counters

Tags: asp.net, rest, performance-testing, connection-pooling, npgsql

First some background:
1. Understand how COnnection Pooling is being used by NPGSQL in ASP.NET REST API

Environment:
- We have a REST API controller that queries first a list of items (to RDS) then per each item in this list we need to obtain some additional values so we use a Parallel.ForEach statement

- Every time we use a connection we dispose it properly
- I've seen that every time this endpoint is called the number of connections increase and then they are removed ok.

Process:

I've followed http://www.npgsql.org/doc/performance.html#performance-counters to check on how NPGSQL is handling connections, also added the following to the connectionstring:
  "CommandTimeout=50000;TIMEOUT=1024;POOLING=True;MINPOOLSIZE=1;MAXPOOLSIZE=100;Use Perf Counters=true;"

but I found a strange outcome:

NumberOfNonPooledConnections and NumberOfPooledConnections is always the same in my case (56) we are using a Parallel.ForEach to query several items.

The value for NumberOfActiveConnectionPools is 1.

At first I couldn't really understand how this is working, was it really using the connection pool ?

Then I stop the process removed the ";POOLING=True;" from the connection string and I have the same result.

Finally I set ";POOLING=false;" and execute again, now the NumberOfPooledConnections went to the roof  it reached 2378, and then it started timing out opening new connections.
I also noted in RDS performance metrics that the number of connections never exeeced 110 connections.

So the questions would be:
What would be the criteria to set the MaxPoolSize parameter ? 100 seems the usual.

In ASP.NET the connection pool is handled by instance ? so all connections being made from the same Application Pool in IIS will be reused or is per execution?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, ASP.NET (the web side) has absolutely no effect on Npgsql's connection pooling or on ADO.NET in general, so it's better to reason about Npgsql and ADO.NET without thinking about web.

Second, you aren't saying which version of Npgsql you're using.

Beyond that, before looking at performance counters, what exactly is the problem you are seeing? Are you seeing too many connections at the PostgreSQL side? You can check this [by querying `pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW).

If Npgsql pooling is on (`Pooling=true` in the connection string, it's also the default), then when you call `NpgsqlConnection.Open()` a physical connection will be taken from the pool if one is available. When you close or dispose that NpgsqlConnection, it will be returned to the pool to be reused later. If you're seeing physical connections going up too much at the PostgreSQL side, that is a probable sign that you are forgetting to close/dispose a connection in your code and you have a leak.

The performance counters feature can be useful to understand what's happening, but unfortunately it isn't well-tested and may contain bugs. So please make sure there's an actual issue before starting to look at it (and at the very least report the Npgsql version you're using).

Comment: Well... thanks for replying... and sorry for not mentioning the version.

1. In production we are using version 3.0.4
2. I upgraded locally to version 4.0.0 to check out the performance counters

The issue was having a "timeout while getting  a connection from the pool" I think the issue was probably related to having a MaxPoolSize set on one env.

Then Npgsql's handles the connection pool per environment.  Just to confirm I created a new app in IIS and deployed the same code, and still have NumberOfActiveConnectionPools = 1

Comment: I don't know what version "3.0.4 2" is :) The latest 3.2 is 3.2.7, which you should be using if 4.0.0 is too bleeding-edge for you. On the other hand, if you're doing to do a major upgrade from an older version, you might as well try to go directly to 4.0.0 - please let us know of any issues you encounter.

Comment: Regarding your exception, having a Max Pool Size is mandatory - you cannot create an infinite number of physical connections (that would quickly overload PostgreSQL). Max Pool Size in itself doesn't cause timeouts; it simply means that open attempts will sometimes block until another physical connection is released and becomes available. You can try to increase the pool size and/or the connection timeout, but this is kind of error frequently points to a simple connection leak in your application (in which case no increase will help).

Comment: Great! thanks well we are using version 3.0.4 (as specified on nuget package manager and on the assembly's version) I think we'll update later this year, we'll let you know how it goes.
awesome explanation on the Max Pool Size thanks ! 
Keep up the good work with npgsql!

Comment: one last question, when setting pooling=false I saw the NumberOfNonPooledConnections  skyrocketed in the client until I started receiving a message about being unable to create new connections (in the server we are fine). We have 
"using (var connection = DatabaseContext.CreateInstance())" and always close the connection  "PgsqlConnection.Close();" not sure why we have so much opened connections ni the client (unless the perf counters are not reliable)

Comment: @MetalGeorge did you resolve this issue because we have the same... we want PgPool to manage the connection pool, but turning off pooling in the application connection string causes all sorts of problems.

Comment: We just kept the transactions small and released connections and it was it. I  believe you should check with @ShayRojansky he may be able to resolve your questions

Comment: @MetalGeorge and others -  if you encounter any issues when turning off pooling, please submit an issue with a code sample on https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql